# Counting each punctuation

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file that contains a large amount of data, and I want to count the number of each punctuation.

For now I only know how to count the whole punctuations of the text but not each of them separated.

I would like to have the number each punctuation in each row saved in a CSV file.

Below are my attempts to get the number of each punctuation, but I got errors like `re.error: nothing to repeat at position 0'`.

```py
news=pd.read_csv("cluesnew.csv")
news['?']= news.string_column.str.count('?')
news['[']= news.string_column.str.count('[')
news[']']= news.string_column.str.count(']')
news['!']= news.string_column.str.count('!')
news[';']= news.string_column.str.count(';')
news['{']= news.string_column.str.count('{')
news['}']= news.string_column.str.count('}')
news['/']= news.string_column.str.count('/')
news['-']= news.string_column.str.count('-')
news['_']= news.string_column.str.count('_')
news[',']= news.string_column.str.count(',')
news['.']= news.string_column.str.count('.')
news[':']= news.string_column.str.count(':')
news['`']= news.string_column.str.count('`')
news['...']= news.string_column.str.count('...')
news.to_csv("cluesnew.csv")
```

Some examples of cluesnew.csv

```
ID string_column
1  In 2017 alone, death due to diabetes was recorded at 10.1 per cent.
2  12.4 per cent of the country's citizens have diabetes.
```

An example of the resulting dataframe would be:

```
string_column                                                         . , [ ] ! ` { ....
In 2017 alone, death due to diabetes was recorded at 10.1 per cent.   1 1 0 0 0 0 0 ....
12.4 per cent of the country's citizens have diabetes.                1 0 0 0 0 1 0 ....
```

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: can you show a sample of your data frame and I assume the punctuation is the list above ?

Comment: regex to extract the matching group plus string length in tandem should be the way to go, but please provide a sample dataframe

Comment: `string.punctuation` and `collections.Counter` can help you. Show us what you tried so far and we can help you develop from there.

Comment: @strawberrylatte, just updated my answer and now you have a complete code that will generate a `CSV` the way you wanted. Check it out, please.

Comment: If possible, post sample of `cluesnew.csv` content, used as the input.

Comment: @accdias i edited my question to include some of the data in the cluesnew.csv

Comment: @strawberrylatte, Just adapted my answer to reflect that. It will read the `CSV` file you point on `source` and write a new one to `target` with the new columns, as you requested. After that you can read the new one with `pandas`, as you are used to, and the new columns will be there. Do not read and write to the same file, pick a new `CSV` to write the resulting new data.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `pandas` to do that. The standard library `csv` module can handle the task.

Here is a possible solution in Python 3 using `csv` module:

```py
from string import punctuation
from collections import OrderedDict
from pathlib import Path
import csv

source = Path('/path/to/source.csv')
target = Path('/path/to/target.csv')

with source.open() as src, target.open('w') as tgt:

    csvreader = csv.reader(src, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    csvwriter = csv.writer(tgt, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    # skip header line from source
    next(csvreader)

    # write the header to target
    csvwriter.writerow(['string_column'] + [_ for _ in punctuation])

    counter = OrderedDict()

    for string_column, *_ in csvreader():
        # reset the counter for each line
        counter.clear()

        string_column = line.rstrip()

        # count punctuation
        for c in punctuation:
            counter[c] = string_column.count(c)

        # write the line
        csvwriter.writerow([string_column] + [counter[_] for _ in punctuation])
```

After that, you can easily read the resulting `target.csv` into a `pandas` data frame if you want to, with something like this:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv(target)
>>> df.columns
Index(['string_column', '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', ''', '(', ')', '*', '+',
       ',', '-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\', ']',
       '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~'],
      dtype='object')
>>>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Indeed but I prefer to use `defaultdict` to be sure the keys will always be in the same order. That's not true for `dict` in all versions of Python.

Comment: I know. But `defaultdict` is implemented on top of `OrderedDict` already and I prefer to use it.

Comment: @accdias would this work with panda? since i'm using panda to read the csv file

Comment: @aws_apprentice, It does make sense because OP wants to write that on a CSV file and for that work, he needs to have all columns in the same order, don't you agree?

Comment: @strawberrylatte, I guess it will. You need to show us more of what you tried so we can help you develop from there. The could I gave you will just put all lines and respective counter in array for use later.

Comment: @aws_apprentice, read que question again and pay attention to the result he wants. It is not explicit written but you can see by inspecting the desired output.

Comment: the output is a dataframe, yours is not. I am downvoting because 1) the desired format is not what OP is asking and 2) this answer uses unneeded tools

Comment: @aws_apprentice, Mine is not supposed to be a complete answer. I just told the author how to have all lines and respective counters on a list and I told him to develop from there. Please, post your solution instead. I'm sure I will learn something and you will help OP more than arguing here. And despite OP saying the output is a dataframe, it is in fact a CSV with fixed length columns. Take a look again.

Comment: when providing an answer, please provide a _complete_ answer, that is the point of an answer. if you wish to provide hints, please do so via the comments section. I suggest revisiting this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to refresh your memory

Comment: @aws_apprentice, I understand your opinion but if you read the OP a little closer you will see that the real question is _"how do I count each punctuation on each line?"_ and that is completely addressed on my answer. I really don't understand why down vote an answer just because you don't like it. If I made mistakes, I'm open to fix them if you point them. Again, post your code instead, I will be glad to read it and learn from it.

Comment: at the bottom of the post, OP asks for the _resulting dataframe_ to look like what he posted, hence he is asking for a dataframe as the final output. the title of the post does not define the desired output. i didn’t downvote because I don’t like the answer, I listed my reasons for downvoting, one of them being that this is not the desired output.

Comment: @aws_apprentice, I've just updated the answer. What do you think? Is it good now? I'm not being sarcastic. I'm really looking for an honest feedback.

Comment: I removed my downvote now that the answer is in the format OP is expecting

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re 
import string

df = pd.DataFrame({'string_column': ['In 2017 alone, death due to diabetes was recorded at 10.1 per cent.', "12.4 per cent of the country's citizens have diabetes."]})
for i in string.punctuation:
    if i == '.':
        df[i] = df['string_column'].str.count(r"{}(?![0-9])".format(re.escape(i)))
    else:
        df[i] = df['string_column'].str.count(re.escape(i))
print(df['.'])
print(df[','])
```

**Output:**

```
0    1
1    1
Name: ., dtype: int64
0    1
1    0
Name: ,, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get all punctuations from your string like this:

```
import string
p = [ch for ch in s if ch in string.punctuation]
```

Then you can count how many times each character (punctuation in this case) is encountered like this:

```
from itertools import groupby
counts = [len(list(punc)) for key, punc in groupby(p)]
```